# Trajan font not displayed properly

Tags: fonts

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{trajan}

\begin{document}
This \texttrjn{is} for test
\end{document}
```

Above code works fine, but in the `.log` file, error shows as:

```
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/trajan\t1trjn.fd)
Missing character: There is no i in font trjnr10!
Missing character: There is no s in font trjnr10!
```

and the text doesn't show in the output, please suggest how can I fix this?

I'm using `MikTeX 2.9` in `Windows10 (3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3))`  and using `LaTeX -> dvips -> PS2PDF`

Also, please confirm any one that is there `Trajan Bold` available?

Comment: Isn't trajan an uppercase font only?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry for my silly question, now only I understood that this particular font works for Uppercase letters only....please excuse....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.fd` file is simple:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{trjn}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{trjn}{m}{n}{ <-> trjnr10 }{}
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{trjn}{bx}{n}{ <-> sub * trjn/m/n }{}
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{trjn}{b}{n}{ <-> sub * trjn/m/n }{}
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{trjn}{m}{sl}{ <-> trjnsl10 }{}
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{trjn}{m}{it}{ <-> sub * trjn/m/sl }{}
\endinput
```

and this hints that there are only the medium weight fonts, available in upright and slanted shapes. No boldface.

Now run `pdflatex nfssfont` and at the prompt type in `trjnr10`, hitting return and again hitting return at the next prompt. The output you get is

[image]

Oh! The font only has the uppercase letters and a few punctuation signs.

Comment: sir, I've tried your suggestion, but still the `.log` file said that `(t1trjn.fd)
Missing character: There is no i in font trjnr10!
Missing character: There is no s in font trjnr10!` is there any thing I need to update? please suggest...

Comment: @MadyYuvi There is ***no*** lowercase letter in the font, so you can't get them.

Comment: sorry, understood, excuse for my silly mistake....